# Number 'e' notation string comparison errors in PowerShell

Tags: powershell-3.0, number-formatting

The following code prints *It's greater than 1*:

```
$value = "1.9964672441318374e-005"
If ($value -ge 1)
{
    Write-Host "It's greater than 1"
}
Else
{
    Write-Host "Smaller than 1"
}
```

I understand that this can be corrected by casting $value to a [double]. I was wondering if anyone else encountered this inconsistent behavior. I say inconsistent because for decimal formatted strings the comparison yields the correct output. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

The quotes make the variable be treated as a string:

```
PS> $v=1.1e3
PS> $v |get-member #-> TypeName : System.Double     

PS> $v="1.1e3"
PS> $v |get-member #-> TypeName : System.String
```

If you remove the quotes on in your original code, you'll find that the comparison works the way that you would expect.